# How to add a new Object to an empty array and display it in the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can anyone help me figure out how to add newUser Object to an empty array called users? The data I send using the POSTMAN inside of req.body is not displayed in the terminal when I run console.log(users)

```
   let users = [];
   app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
     let username = req.body.username;
     let password = req.body.password;
     /* typeof and undefined is added for the scenario 
        if the request body has either username or password object only;
        OR any isn't declared in the request body. */

     if (username !== null &&
       username !== "" &&
       typeof username !== "undefined" &&
       password !== null &&
       password !== "" &&
       typeof password !== "undefined") {

       let requestBody = "";
       req.on("data", (addUser) => {
         requestBody += addUser;
       });
       req.on("end", () => {
         requestBody = JSON.parse(requestBody);
         let newUser = {
           "username": requestBody.username,
           "password": requestBody.password
         }
         users.push(newUser);
         console.log(users);
       });

       res.send(`User ${username} successfully registered`);
     } else {
       res.send(`Please input both username and password.`);
     }
   });
```

Comment: Can you please share how you are taking in parameter addUser ? also try logging requestBody before you declare newUser.

Answer (score 0):

From the express [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)

> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json()

So you'll need to do this somewhere at the top of your file,

```
app.use(express.json);
```

Also, with express, you don't need to use `req.on` to parse incoming data, you can simply do the following,

```
   let users = [];
   app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
     let username = req.body.username;
     let password = req.body.password;
     /* typeof and undefined is added for the scenario 
        if the request body has either username or password object only;
        OR any isn't declared in the request body. */

     if (username !== null &&
       username !== "" &&
       typeof username !== "undefined" &&
       password !== null &&
       password !== "" &&
       typeof password !== "undefined") {

       users.push({
         username,
         password
       });
       console.log(users);

       res.send(`User ${username} successfully registered`);
     } else {
       res.send(`Please input both username and password.`);
     }
   });
```

Here's your example on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@painotpi/LongYoungInterpreter#index.js)

Comment: Hi, Yes. I figured out req.on isn't necessary for express.js I used that when I'm learning node.js and since express.js makes everything simpler, I figured out to directly declare `push()` inside the if statement. But using your example above will give an error because newUser is not defined, so I had to declare this before `push()`

`let newUser = { "username": req.body.username, "password": req.body.password}`

Thanks for the response though :)

Comment: @jcpurrfect yeah sorry that was a typo, fixed that.